# Unity 2D - How can I shoot, by swiping up or down, whilst aiming?

Tags: unity, c#, input, touch, multitouch

I am quite new to Unity and C# (in fact, this is my first project). I am creating a simple 2D top down view shooter game. The game is aimed to be played on smartphones.

I have a virtual, fixed joystick. I would like to be able to aim with one finger (on the joystick, on the left), and swipe up or down to fire (with another finger on the right). Right now, I can shoot perfectly. Where the character aims is based on the joystick. The problem is that the joystick can be controlled from anywhere on the left side of the screen if only one finger is on the screen (which makes the aiming weird). And, if I try to swipe on the right side of the screen (where the swiping should occur whilst playing), whilst aiming, the angle will start to be influenced by the second finger (the one that is swiping) as well. Also, I can't shoot while aiming (when I swipe, no effect happens, except the aiming angle gets glitchy).

So what I would like to know is,

1. How can I aim only when touching the joystick?
2. How can I make it possible to not let other fingers influence the
   angle of aiming?
3. How can I shoot by swiping, whilst aiming?

This is the swiping script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Swipe : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    private bool tap,swipeUp,swipeDown, swipeLeft, swipeRight;
    private bool isDraging = false;
    private Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta;
 
 
     // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        tap = swipeUp = swipeDown = swipeLeft = swipeRight = false;
 
 
        #region
        if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
        {
 
            if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began){
 
                isDraging = true;
                tap = true;
                startTouch = Input.touches[0].position;
           
 
            }
            else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
 
            isDraging = false;
            Reset();
 
 
        }
 
        }
 
 
        #endregion
 
 
 
        #region Standalone Inputs
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
 
            tap = true;
            isDraging = true;
            startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
 
 
 
        }else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
 
            isDraging = false;
            Reset();
 
 
        }
        #endregion
   
        // Calculate the distance
        swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        if(isDraging)
        {
 
            if(Input.touches.Length > 0)
                swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
            else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
                swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;      
        }
   
   
        // Did we cross the deadzone?
        if (swipeDelta.magnitude > 125)
        {
 
            // Which direction?
            float x = swipeDelta.x;
            float y = swipeDelta.y;
            if(Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
            {
 
                // left or right
                if (x < 0)
                    swipeLeft = true;
 
                else
                    swipeRight = true;
 
 
 
            }
            else{
 
                // up or down
                if (y < 0)
                    swipeDown = true;
 
                else
                    swipeUp = true;
           
            }
 
 
            Reset();
 
        }
 
 
    }
 
 
 
 
   
   
   
     private void Reset()
    {
 
        startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        isDraging = false;
 
 
    }
 
 
 
 
 
 
    public Vector2 SwipeDelta { get { return swipeDelta;}}
    public bool SwipeUp { get { return swipeUp;}}
    public bool SwipeDown { get { return swipeDown;}}
    public bool SwipeLeft { get { return swipeLeft;}}
    public bool SwipeRight{ get { return swipeRight;}}
}
```

This is the Gesture Detection script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class GestrueDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
public Shooting other;
 
public Swipe swipeControls;
 
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
   private void Update()
    {
 
        if (GameObject.Find("robot") != null)
{
   
        if (swipeControls.SwipeLeft)
              Debug.Log("LeftSwipe");
             
 
        if (swipeControls.SwipeRight)
               Debug.Log("RightSwipe");
           
           
            if (swipeControls.SwipeUp)
         
            other.Shoot();
               
 
                 
 
            if (swipeControls.SwipeDown)
         
            other.Shoot();
                 
 
                 
 
       
}
        }
```

And this is the script to aim:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class joystickShoot : MonoBehaviour {
    public Shooting other;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Swipe swipeControls;
    private bool touchStart = false;
 
    private Vector2 pointA;
    private Vector2 pointB;
    public Transform player;
    public float speed = 15.0f;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
 
    public Transform circle;
    public Transform outerCircle;
 
    private Vector2 startingPoint;
    private int leftTouch = 99;
 
   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < Input.touchCount){
            Touch t = Input.GetTouch(i);
            Vector2 touchPos = getTouchPosition(t.position); // * -1 for perspective cameras
            if(t.phase == TouchPhase.Began){
                if(t.position.x > Screen.width / 2){
                   
                   
                 
                }else{
                    leftTouch = t.fingerId;
                     pointA = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
                    startingPoint = touchPos;
                    touchStart = true;
                }
            }else if(t.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && leftTouch == t.fingerId){
               touchStart = true;
                Vector2 offset = touchPos - startingPoint;
                Vector2 direction = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(offset, 1.0f);
               
                 pointB = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
             
                aimCharacter(direction);
 
                circle.transform.position = new Vector2(outerCircle.transform.position.x + direction.x, outerCircle.transform.position.y + direction.y);
 
            }else if(t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && leftTouch == t.fingerId){
                leftTouch = 99;
                circle.transform.position = new Vector2(outerCircle.transform.position.x, outerCircle.transform.position.y);
            }else{
 
                touchStart = false;
            }
            ++i;
        }
 
    }
    Vector2 getTouchPosition(Vector2 touchPosition){
        return GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, transform.position.z));
    }
 
    void aimCharacter(Vector2 direction){
     
        Vector2 lookDir = pointB - pointA;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        rb.rotation = angle;
       
    }
   
 
     private void FixedUpdate() {
          if(touchStart){
            Vector2 offset = pointB - pointA;
 
 
           
           
           
            Vector2 direction = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(offset, 1.0f);
            aimCharacter(direction * 1);
 
     }
     }
    void shootBullet(){
     
    }
}
```

Any ideas regarding what I can do? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your swipe script is looking only at touch zero, which will often point to the finger on the joystick. You're also setting touchStart to false if you find a second touch - even if there's still a finger on the joystick - when I think you meant to set it to false only when there is no finger on the joystick.

Comment: Thanks! So how do I make the swipe script look at multiple touches? And also, I didn't really understand the second part. Where should I set the touch start to false then? Thanks!